# Delete record with condition in a CTE table

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, common-table-expression

I have a CTE table who looks like this:

```
id  prsn  A  B  C
1    2    0  0  1
1    3    0  1  0
2    1    0  1  1
2    1    0  1  0
2    2    1  0  1
3    1    0  1  0
3    1    0  1  1
```

I want to delete the records that are duplicated in columns "id" and "prsn"
The condition to determine which record it's going to be deleted its Column "C" > 0

So If a raw is duplicated on "id" and "prsn" I want to keep the raw with "C" > 0

The expected output:

```
id  prsn  A  B  C
1    2    0  0  1
1    3    0  1  0
2    1    0  1  1
2    2    1  0  1
3    1    0  1  1
```

I'm working with CTE tables in jupyter

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what are "CTE tables".  You cannot *delete* rows from a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a record is unique you can create column D using the row_number() function in SQL. This lets you reset the row number per unique record so you can then delete any non-unique record where the row number has not reset and is > 1.
So this would be:

```
with CTE as
(select row_number() over (partition by id, prsn order by id, prsn) as D from yourdata)
delete from CTE where D > 1 and C = 0
```